# Generating SeretKey by KeyGenerator.generateKey() taking long time on debian

Tags: java, aes, secret-key

I am generating 128 bit AES SecretKey from KeyGenerator(javax.crypto.KeyGenerator), it is working fine on the Windows system but when moved to Debian(Ubuntu) it's taking a long time to generate. I am not sure if it's related to a memory issue?

---

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(keysize, SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong());
return keyGen.generateKey();
```

---

Comment: You can calculate elapsed execution time of your Java programs via : `System.currentTimeinMillis()` / `System.nanoTime()`. Add them at different lines and see how long each events takes. That would give you a better idea.

Comment: I did the same... it's like random... sometimes more than 10 mins

Comment: May be the OS has not gathered enough entropy for providing random values? What Ubuntu and Java version do you use?

Comment: is there any way to check or force to gather enough entropy? As many of our users are on debian

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a long research resolved the issue by starting "haveged" service for entropy

```
apt-get install haveged
update-rc.d haveged defaults
service haveged start
```